# Cant Find Database file in Eclipse for Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, eclipse

I have been doing an android database application project recently.When i tried to execute. I cant find the folder 'databases' in the file explorer of the DDMS. I checked the following path /data/data/packagename/databases,but there i could not find databases folder and my database file.

I have attached the code for database helper class
please help me if there is any error that is preventing me from creating the database or is it wrong with my eclipse. Because even some of my existing projects also don't show up with the databases folder inside them.

DBclass.java:

```
package pack.andyxdb;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBclass {

    public static final String KEY_TIMESTAMP = "Timestamp";
    public static final String KEY_UNIQUEID = "UniqueID";
    public static final String KEY_DEVICETYPE = "Devicetype";
    public static final String KEY_RSSI = "RSSI";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DannyZ.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Data";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context ourContext;
    private DbHelper dbh;
    private SQLiteDatabase odb;

    private static final String USER_MASTER_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE+ "("
                    + KEY_TIMESTAMP + " INTEGER ,"
                    + KEY_UNIQUEID  + " INTEGER, " + KEY_DEVICETYPE + " TEXT, " + KEY_RSSI + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )";
    //CREATE TABLE `DannyZ` (

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(USER_MASTER_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // if DATABASE VERSION changes
            // Drop old tables and call super.onCreate()
        }
    }

    public DBclass(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
        dbh = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    }

    public DBclass open() throws SQLException {
        odb = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbh.close();
    }

    public long insertrecord(int timestamp, int uniqueID,String Device, int RSSI) throws SQLException{
        // Log.d("", col1);
        // Log.d("", col2);

        ContentValues IV = new ContentValues();

        IV.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
        IV.put(KEY_UNIQUEID, uniqueID );
        IV.put(KEY_DEVICETYPE, Device != "");
        IV.put(KEY_RSSI, RSSI );

        return odb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, IV);
        // returns a number >0 if inserting data is successful
    }

    public void updateRow(long rowID, String col1, String col2,String col3,String col4) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, col1);
        values.put(KEY_UNIQUEID, col2);
        values.put(KEY_DEVICETYPE, col3);
        values.put(KEY_RSSI, col4);

        try {
            odb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_RSSI + "=" + rowID, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public boolean delete() {
        return odb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllTitles() {
        // using simple SQL query
        return odb.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + "ORDER BY "+KEY_RSSI, null);
    }

    public Cursor getallCols(String id) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = odb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_TIMESTAMP,
                KEY_UNIQUEID, KEY_DEVICETYPE, KEY_RSSI }, null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.e("getallcols zmv", "opening successfull");
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getColsById(String id) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = odb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_TIMESTAMP,
                KEY_UNIQUEID,KEY_DEVICETYPE }, KEY_RSSI + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
        Log.e("getallcols zmv", "opening successfull");
        return mCursor;
    }
}
```

also my MainActivity.java code is here. Here i try to insert the data into database by making use of submit button. When i hit submit button the app does not stay for long time and says unfortunately myapp has stopped.my curious concern has been  is my database being created or not?

please do help me thanks

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView list_lv;
    private EditText txt1;
    private EditText txt2;
    private EditText txt3;
    private EditText txt4;
    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn2;
    private DBclass db;

    private ArrayList<String> collist_1;
    private ArrayList<String> collist_2;
    private ArrayList<String> collist_3;
    private ArrayList<String> collist_4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        collist_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        collist_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        collist_3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        collist_4 = new ArrayList<String>();

        items();
        // getData();
    }

    private void items() {
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        txt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        // list_lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dblist);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getData();
                viewData();
            }

            private void viewData() {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, viewActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitData();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void submitData() {
        int a = Integer.parseInt( txt1.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt( txt2.getText().toString());
        String c = txt3.getText().toString();
        int d = Integer.parseInt( txt4.getText().toString());

        db = new DBclass(this);

        long num = 0;
        try {
            db.open();
            num = db.insertrecord(a, b,c,d);
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Duplicate value"+e,2000).show();

        } finally {
            //getData();
        }
        if (num > 0)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Row number: " + num, 2000).show();
        else if (num == -1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Duplicate value", 4000).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error while inserting", 2000).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The application is working as expected? Are you trying to access the data folder on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: Can you attach the Logcat?

Comment: @Alex The application is not working as expected. I am unable to make sure whether the database is being created or not. I dont find any databases folder in my package

Answer (score -2):

Create object of helper class in your activity onCreate method for creating the database file in android app

```
DBclass db=new DBclass(context);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: He is asking how can he view database created by his app

Comment: He is not able to see database because its not created till now.Once he will create object in onCreate method than only database folder will get created

Comment: i think i have created the object as you said already here is the code public DBclass(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
        dbh = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    }                                                  @Jai

Comment: I am talking about creating object of DBClass in onCreate() method of MainActivity class(Your activity) and no need to create in submitData() method as it will be called only after button click.Database should be created in onCreate method of activity.

Comment: The code you have mentioned in above comment is like you are creating helper class object in your data base adapter class(DBclass).that is fine but for creating database in your application you have to create object of Data base adapter class(DBclass ) in your onCreate methos of your Activity.

Comment: Since you have already created member variable db in you Activity. So just add    db=new DBclass(this); in your onCreate() method of Activity class